# Qt Android: Cannot find -ljvm

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm using `Qt` and I compiled my project for Android ARMv7, but I get this error: `Cannot find -ljvm`. Whereas I included this commands into .pro file:

```
android: {
    QT += androidextras
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux
    LIBS += -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm
}
```

Also when I use `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, I get this error: `undefined reference to JNI_CreateJavaVM`. What reasons of the errors?

Comment: You need a version of the lib for the right arch (arm). That's the reason why you are getting the "skipping incompatible <library> while searching for ljvm".

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, Java have got only one ljvm in amd/server/, it is libjvm.so. I can running Java code with QAndroidExtras, but I have to use pure JNI for Android SDK classes.

Comment: Yeah, I've read about your requirement but the error you are encountering it's a matter or architecture. Can't help further, sorry.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo thanks, I found a new jni.h path : `Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/`. I think this jni.h for Android, but I get error: `JNI_CreateJavaVM was not declared in this scope`. I included for linux-g++ (desktop) and Android into .pro file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23786707/